# How to deploy Nuxt.js(SSR with Express.js) to Vercel via Gitlab?

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware, vercel

I have successfully built my app and only remain step is deploy to the host **Vercel** via my repo on **Gitlab**

I use **Nuxt.js(SSR type)** with server **Express.js** and [**`Nuxt.js Now Builder`**](https://github.com/nuxt/now-builder) to deploy host Vercel via repo Gitlab

**This is structure**

```
api/
--| index.js
now.json
nuxt.config.js
```

**In `index.js`**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const products = require("./routes/product/products");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Import API Routes
app.use(products);

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: "/api",
  handler: app
};
```

**In `now.json`**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "nuxt.config.js",
            "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder",
            "config": {
                "serverFiles": [
                    "package.json"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**And in `nuxt.config.js`**

```
...
serverMiddleware: [
    // API middleware
    "~/api/index.js"
  ]
...
```

According to [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs), deploying is very easy, just commit and push code to Gitlab to complete

However, i always get error as below
[image]
I don't understand why? I don't know what i missed. Please help me and i'm very grateful for the help

Comment: Did you find a solution? Would you please share?
I'm struggling with the same setup.

Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexanderBenjamin In now.json, the `"serverFiles"` should point to files to be included along with nuxt's default (`.nuxt`), in this case the path which are being used for `serverMiddleware`. So you have to add `"api/**"` to `serverFiles` config

Comment: hi Alexander Benjamin, until now, i don't find any solution for this, i have given up on it because there are so few documentation and support community. I frozen with it, so i switch to another platform :D

Comment: Hi? have you found a solution? I got a solution for the many hours that I passed. let me know if not, maybe i can help you

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

narze, thank you for your solution, unfortunately it didn't work for me but pointed me in the right direction.

Here is my working ***now.json***:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "env": {
        "ON_VERCEL": "true"
    },
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "api/**/*.js",
            "use": "@now/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "nuxt.config.js",
            "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {  "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "api/index.js" },
        { "src": "/api", "dest": "api/index.js" },
        { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "$1" }
    ]
}
```

serverMiddleware in ***nuxt.config.js***

```
serverMiddleware: isServerlessEnvironment ? [] : [
  '~/api/index.js'
],
```

where `isServerlessEnvironment` defined on the very top of nuxt.config.js as

```
const isServerlessEnvironment = process.env.ON_VERCEL=="true"
```

- API files need to be compiled with @now/node.
- Routes need to be set up to separate nuxt routes from api routes.
- With conditional `isServerlessEnvironment` in nuxt.config.js it works on local server with `yarn dev` and vercel server.

Credits to this article: [Nuxt.js with an Express.js API server running on Now.sh](https://arunas.dev/nuxt-js-with-an-express-js-api-server-running-on-now-sh/)

Thank you all for being helpful :)

Comment: Hi @TT. I am asking a question indeed. I'm sorry, I do believe I clicked on 'Add comment' link. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @TT., I've just found a solution. So I will delete the current answer and post the correct, actual, answer :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with deploying `Nuxt` on `Vercel` with `serverMiddleware`'s which returned `405 (Not Allowed)`. I solved it using this doc [Nuxt Vercel Builder](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/nuxt/vercel-builder?categoryPage=27) by specifying property `serverFiles` in `vercel.json`:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": ["server-middleware/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> If you need to include files in the server lambda that are not built
> by webpack or within static/, such as a local module or
> serverMiddleware, you may specify them with this option. Each item can
> be a glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late now lol. But I wrote an article to demonstrate the whole process to get your app up and running on Vercel. You can find it [here](https://dev.to/mohammedayman2018/deploy-nuxt-express-app-on-vercel-with-ssr-functionality-4fi3).